# Find interval of the value for $\sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} $.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find interval of the value for:
$\sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} $.

I know that  $\int^{\infty}_{n=3} \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} dx = \frac{1}{15}.$ Thus, this should be the lower bound of the interval. But what about the upper bound?

I assumed the answer should be $\int^{\infty}_{n=3} \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} dx  + \int^{3}_{2} \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} dx$, which should be equal to $  \frac{1}{15} + \frac{4}{165} = \frac{15}{165}$, however that is not an answer. Where am I erring?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to estimate a sum such as this. I don't know which method you are "supposed" to use.

Since the summand (call it $f(n)$) is a decreasing function of $n$, one of the most straightforward methods is to say $\int_{n}^{n+1} f(x)\; dx \le f(n) \le \int_{n-1}^n f(x)\; dx$, so

$$ \frac{1}{15} = \int_3^\infty \frac{4}{(4x+3)^2}\; dx \le \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} \le \int_2^\infty \frac{4}{(4x+3)^2}\; dx = \frac{1}{11}$$

Hmm: that's what you did, except you didn't reduce the fraction to lowest terms: $15/165 = 1/11$.

Or you could use this upper bound for $n \ge 4$ and evaluate $f(3)$ explicitly, so

$$ \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} \le \frac{4}{(4\cdot 3+3)^2} + \int_3^\infty \frac{4}{(4x+3)^2}\; dx = \frac{19}{225}$$

Note that this is slightly better.

Or for something still better, you could use the fact that the summand is convex to say $f(n) \le \int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2} f(x)\; dx$, so that

$$ \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} \le \int_{2.5}^\infty  \frac{4}{(4x+3)^2}\; dx = \frac{1}{13}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well..there can be many forms of upperbounds, but I'm presenting this closest one which I could calculate.

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} <\sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \frac{4}{(4n)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Now you can use the fact that : $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{(n)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Therefore : $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \frac{1}{(n)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{5}{4}$$

Hence,

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=3} \frac{4}{(4n+3)^2} < \frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{5}{16}$$

Comment: The course's answer is 19/225, which I think they got from adding f(3) to the integral. Though I thought f(2) should be added to make more sense?

Comment: @Haim You should specify that explicitly in your question, because there are many ways to find upper bound some of which may not answer your question .